# Firebase Firestore get() counts as 3 api calls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been working on a simple app this week to learn to use Firestore and I've been watching my api calls on the quotas page. All week I had barely used 400 calls but suddenly today the reporting shot up over 50,000. Now, my Firestore only has 2 collections, and one collection only has 8 documents in it. So there's not a lot of data. My app is still very primitive and can only either collection, and add/update documents in only one of those. I mention all that to explain that my app does not do much, so it was very surprising when I saw the usage.

I started digging into the individual calls and noticed that when I perform a single call:

```
let db = fire.firestore();
db.collection("tags").get()
.then( snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot);
})
.catch( error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

the Cloud Firestore API Calls counter increased by 3. There are no custom functions, no database rules other than

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't looked at creating/updating documents yet, but would anyone know why this one get() would count as 3 api calls?

Comment: How many documents are stored in that collection?

Comment: Only 1 document that contains about 20 booleans. It's structured like:
{
    tag1: true,
    tag2: true,
    tag3: true...
}

It's being used to populate an autocomplete field so that I can search documents in the other collection by those tags

Comment: Are you sure that code is only being executed once? Is there any context you can provide or isolate that code snippet?

Comment: I simplified the code to what I think is only one call. It's only being logged to the console once. I'm using React and this code is in the componentDidMount method.

Comment: I am assuming this is due to your security rules. Here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations

Answer (score 3):

#### Disclaimer:

*I am NOT suggesting this solves your issue of reaching 50,000+ API calls, however I am suggesting this will most likely be an issue you have within that quota.*

---

> Viewing & editing your project's data through Firestore's console will
> count towards your overall `Cloud Firestore API Calls` quota.

Again you may **not** find this helpful, but more times than not users will test their application (whether it be running an auth, writing a new value for a field, or a cloud function) **while watching the data change.** This will result in inconsistent quota increases as you are essentially reading / writing in two places at once.

I recommend trying this through observation of the app **only** with log statements best describing the processes occurring. If you are *still* seeing strange quota increases, unfortunately it resides in *your code*, not with Google. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If in case security rule is the reason, just try with the following Security rule until the app is in the development process:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```