# GCP - How are Cloud Firestore API Calls charged?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Despite not performing too many read/write operations - **170r, 4w** to my Firestore database, I appear to have a huge number of API calls - **15,093** (**See image below**). The cause of this high calls to read/write ratio should be accounted to my application's use of network streams.  My question is, should this be considered as a billable metric, or should I not worry if this runs into the millions so long as read/write are within limits (theoretically, I've never seen this happen on my own account).

I'm inclined to believe that I needn't worry about this metric, as I can't seem to find it under either the Firebase or GCP quotas page.

It may also be considered that I use the google maps and directions API from GCP, although this aren't nearly used as much as Firestore.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing), you are charged for the following:

> 1. The number of documents you read, write, and delete.
> 2. The amount of storage that your database uses, including overhead
>    for metadata and indexes.
> 3. The amount of network bandwidth that you use.

Comment: Do you know if these API calls might affect bandwidth?

Comment: The API is called every time an operation is executed, so this metric shouldn't directly be billed, but of course the operation itself will.

Comment: Another [proof](https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD&filter=firestore) that it is not billable.

Comment: If the API call occurs every time an operation is executed, why are there 15,093 calls to my 174 operations?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783292/firebase-firestore-get-counts-as-3-api-calls) might be part of the answer.

Comment: If you suspect that it is not the above then you need to create a new Stackoverflow as the main question I believe has been answered.

Comment: @danyL potentially, I'll try to observe this directly through the log and ensure all browser clients are closed.

Comment: Btw, I think my previous question about 15k calls to 174 operations is a mistake as non billable calls are counted in that total.

Comment: @danyL I agree my question has been answered.

Comment: What @danyL says seems plausible. As for the reason the API is called multiple times for a single operation, honestly who knows, I haven't found anything in google's documentation. Perhaps GCP support should clarify this issue, it may be intended behavior just as well as a bug.